# Optional argument copy in constructor

Tags: python, api

I'm designing API. I have a class which stores some large table:

```
class TableHolder:
    def __init__(self, table, ...):
        self.table = table
```

I want to avoid user confusion and am making a copy of the table in the constructor.

```
class TableHolder:
    def __init__(self, table, ...):
        self.table = list(table)
```

The problem is that I have many methods and functions which generate such tables and immediately create TableHolder returning it. Those functions do not store table itself and there is no need to make a copy in the constructor for this cases.

```
class TableHolder:
    def __init__(self, table, ...):
        self.table = list(table)

    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, size, callback):
        table = [callback(x) for x in range(size)]
        return cls(table, ...)
```

So I'm looking for a way to tell the constructor do not make a copy. Of course, the simplest solution is separate flag:

```
class TableHolder:
    def __init__(self, table, table_exclusive=False, ...):
        if not table_exclusive:
            table = list(table)
        self.table = table
```

I don't like it. It exposures to the end user some functionality not relevant to the class purposes and could confuse more than just not to make a copy at all.

```
class TableHolder:
    def __init__(self, table, ...):
        self.internal_init(list(table), ...)

    @classmethod
    def _new_exclusive(cls, table, ...):
        self = cls.__new__(cls)
        self.internal_init(table, ...)

    def internal_init(self, table, ...)
        self.table = table
```

This looks terrible inside the class but has a nice interface outside of class.

The last option I found is some marker for the table:

```
class TableHolder:
    class exclusive:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def __init__(self, table, ...):
        if isinstance(table, self.exclusive):
            table = table.value
        else:
            table = list(table)
        self.table = table

    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, size, callback):
        table = [callback(x) for x in range(size)]
        return cls(cls.exclusive(table), ...)
```

I like this option the most because it is transparent for a future possible successors, allows to handle multiple arguments separately (one could be exclusive while another not).

Can it be better?

Comment: Is your problem that you almost always need to copy but occasionally don't, that you almost never need to copy but occasionally do, or that you always need to copy except when calling some specific method of this same class, or is it just sometimes yes and sometimes no haphazardly?